# CloudFoundary - How to get the artifact version installed in an app?

Tags: cloud-foundry

We push the artifactory to app with below command:

In this example: `cf push app-name1 -p target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` we are pushing `api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` on `app-name1`.

So, I need to know this version(0.0.1)

`maifest.yml` has artifactory version to be deployed

---

How to get the artifactory version(details) installed on any app?

Comment: You are versioning your Archive as `0.0.1` .. You are pushing that to the Cloudfoundry...But expecting that to be retrieved from the Cloudfoundry... Looks different!! You can maintain it any where for reference., Why you expect or look into foundry to give you these details ? Cloudfoundry just packs your apps as containers and stary running ... It doesn’t hold these sort of data straightaway

Comment: @Arun can I use `cf set-environment-groups` to store key as appname and value as artifact version? And later retrieve those values...if yes, please provide an answer...

Comment: You could use `cf set-env` to plug in your version number so that you can retrieve it later. You can also put that in the manifest.yml in an `env:` block. If you for example set `APP_VERSION: 0.0.1`, inside your app you could look at the env variable `APP_VERSION` and retrieve that version number.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Can Cloud foundry notify with environment details to a client user, whenever `cf push` executes? We don't want to poll `cf env`

Comment: @overexchange - Sorry, I don't follow. What "client user" are you talking about? Where would this client user be located and how would your CF foundation interact with it? You can get a lot of stuff from the firehose, so maybe that's an option. It's just not clear what you're asking. You may need to start a new question and clarify.

Comment: @DanielMikusa here is a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599632/how-to-notify-environment-change-of-each-app). Front end end(angular) to be notified by backend(say Flask framework using Python), when environment has new data(`cf env`)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you would want, but you can see the *various environment configuration settings for your application* by doing the following:

1. Log in to your cloud foundry environment and fill out the following prompts:

   `cf login`
2. Type `cf env <app>`  where `<app>` is the *name of the application as specified within your manifest file*. This will display various environment configurations such as: application_id, application_name, application_uris, space related information, version, etc... An example output of `cf env <app>` is the following:

   ```
   Getting env variables for app <app> in org <org> / space dev as <user...OK
   System-Provided:


   {
    "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
     "application_id": "<id>",
     "application_name": "<app_name>",
     "application_uris": [
      "<url>"
     ],
     "application_version": "<version>",
     "cf_api": "<cf_api>",
     "limits": {
      "disk": 1024,
      "fds": 16384,
      "mem": 1024
     },
     "name": "<name>",
     "space_id": "<space_id>",
     "space_name": "dev",
     "uris": [
      "<uri1>"
     ],
     "users": null,
     "version": "<version>"
    }
   }

   No user-defined env variables have been set

   No running env variables have been set

   Staging Environment Variable Groups:
   REPOSITORY_ROOT: <url>
   REPOSITORY_ROOT_S3: <url>
   ```

Hopefully that is what you were looking for!

Comment: In this example: `cf push app-name1 -p target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` we are pushing `api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` on `app-name1`. So, I need to know this version(0.0.1)

Comment: Push the app with name as `api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. You can have a route called `app-name1` for public consumption. For new version (0.0.2), move the route. This is the how you can do blue-green deployments.